# Java 8 array madness: empty arrays seem to have length 1

Tags: arrays, stream, java-8

This code should count words in a file.  Each blank line contributes +1, even though a line full of whitespace should split to an empty array.

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class WordCount {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Path p = Paths.get(args[0]);
    if(!Files.exists(p)) {
      System.err.println("File "+ args[0] + "does not exist.");
      return;
    }
    try {
      /*int dracula =*/ Files.lines(p)
      .filter( e -> !(e.matches("^\\s+$")))
      .map(e -> e.split("\\s+"))
      //.mapToInt(e -> e.length)
      //.sum();
      .forEach(e -> System.out::println);
      //System.out.println(dracula);
      int[] foo = new int[0];
      System.out.println(foo.length);
    } catch(IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the sample file I ran it on.

```
martine.space.cadet  mashewske.matt haack

Jack jacob
```

Here is the octal dump of it.

```
Tue Mar 28:16:06:streams> od -bc headache.txt
0000000   155 141 162 164 151 156 145 056 163 160 141 143 145 056 143 141
           m   a   r   t   i   n   e   .   s   p   a   c   e   .   c   a
0000020   144 145 164 040 040 155 141 163 150 145 167 163 153 145 056 155
           d   e   t           m   a   s   h   e   w   s   k   e   .   m
0000040   141 164 164 040 150 141 141 143 153 012 012 112 141 143 153 040
           a   t   t       h   a   a   c   k  \n  \n   J   a   c   k    
0000060   152 141 143 157 142 012 012 012                                
           j   a   c   o   b  \n  \n  \n                                
0000070
```

Comment: I fear that the `split` gives you an array of one empty `String`.

Comment: And it may not be filtered out because it contains 0 blank caracters (try putting a `*` instead of a `+` in `filter`.

Comment: This is an irritating glitch.  Drestin, filtering with * does not work.  This program *should* work correctly. I consider this "feature" to be a big fat bug.

Comment: What are you talking about? Filtering with `*` does work and gives 5 words. Isn't it what you want?

Comment: Your example program can’t produce that output, as `.forEach(e -> System.out::println)` doesn’t compile. Even after fixing, it will print something like `[Ljava.lang.String;@1b28c1fa`…

Comment: Apparently, the removal of trailing empty strings is only applied to split fragments, not the the string itself (if it is an empty string), if no match of the delimiter pattern has been found.

Answer (score 1):

Note the added line highlighted by a comment.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Files;
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<String> foo = new ArrayList<String>();
        foo.add("     ");
        foo.add("");
        foo.add("   q\n\n");
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile("^\\s*$");  //spot blank lines
        Path p = Paths.get("jack.txt");
        try
        {
            int goo = Files.lines(p)
                .filter(e -> !r.matcher(e).matches())  //get rid of blank lines
                .mapToInt(s -> s.split("\\s+").length)
                .sum();
                //.forEach(e -> System.out.println("line:" + e));
            System.out.println("words:  " + goo);
        }
        catch(Exception annoyingMartine)
        {
            //quack
        }
        foo.stream()
            .filter(e -> !r.matcher(e).matches())
            .forEach(e -> System.out.println("line:" + e));
    }
}
```